# Can I answer a challenge twice?

Tags: discussion

Sometimes, I play [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) or [quine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quine), and I find an answer more than once, for two different languages. (I know [popularity-contest](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/popularity-contest) dosen't count.) Can I post another answer, assuming that the rules of the contest don't say otherwise?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

## Yes

You can post as many answers as you want for a question unless forbidden by the question.

Comment: I assume this works for both two answers in the same language and different ones? Or is it just different?

Comment: @ASCIIThenANSI This applies to any question and any answer.

Comment: @ASCIIThenANSI Yes. Of course, if the answers are very similar, you can put them both in the same answer, the shorter one at the top. But if they are different approaches, I'd always post two answers. Also, I'm not sure what you were getting at about popularity contests in your question - I'd say the same rules apply there.

Comment: @MartinBüttner Thanks for the clarification.